# No sound - ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, apt, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I just ran `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` and suddenly there was no sound.

I rebooted and I heard the bios boot sound but when Ubuntu boots there is no sound. I followed instructions on [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/469804/ubuntu-14-04-no-sound) post but when I uninstall `alsa-base` I couldn't install it back and `apt` says there is no install candidate :

```
Package alsa-base is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'alsa-base' has no installation candidate
```

I tried to do [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/395414/how-to-install-alsa-base-and-pulseaudio) but it doesn't work, `apt` just gets 404 on that repo.

Now I can't even get to the System settings page since `alsa-base` was uninstalled.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot give you an answer, but we are many to have the same problem for the last 24h after upgrading from pulseaudio 3 to 3.1. To confirm that this is the same issue, run in a terminal

```
grep pulse /var/log/apt/history.log
```

If you obtain something like

```
Upgrade: libpulsedsp:amd64 (1:8.0-0ubuntu3, 1:8.0-0ubuntu3.1), pulseaudio:amd64 (1:8.0-0ubuntu3, 1:8.0-0ubuntu3.1), libpulse0:amd64 (1:8.0-0ubuntu3, 1:8.0-0ubuntu3.1), libpulse-mainloop-glib0:amd64 (1:8.0-0ubuntu3, 1:8.0-0ubuntu3.1), pulseaudio-module-x11:amd64 (1:8.0-0ubuntu3, 1:8.0-0ubuntu3.1), pulseaudio-module-bluetooth:amd64 (1:8.0-0ubuntu3, 1:8.0-0ubuntu3.1), pulseaudio-utils:amd64 (1:8.0-0ubuntu3, 1:8.0-0ubuntu3.1)
```

please go on this [link](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/1643847) and report that this bug is affecting you as well to increase the priority.

Comment: Ok i flagged this issue as affecting me also. but the problem still remains that now i don't have`alsa-base` installed. since i removed it, apt-get cant find the package anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The following procedure worked for me:

## 1 purge the package

```
sudo apt purge libpulsedsp pulseaudio libpulse0 libpulse-mainloop-glib0 pulseaudio-module-x11 pulseaudio-module-bluetooth pulseaudio-utils
```

## 2 keep track of the additional removed packages, in my case

```
checkbox-converged checkbox-gui gdm3 gnome-control-center gnome-orca gnome-session gnome-settings-daemon gnome-shell gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio indicator-bluetooth indicator-sound libasound2-plugins libcanberra-pulse libespeak1 libfluidsynth1 libfreerdp-plugins-standard liboxideqt-qmlplugin liboxideqtcore0 liboxideqtquick0 libqt5feedback5 libqt5multimedia5 libsdl-image1.2 libsdl1.2debian libunity-webapps0 qml-module-qtfeedback qml-module-ubuntu-components qml-module-ubuntu-test qml-module-ubuntu-web qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-toolkit-plugin speech-dispatcher speech-dispatcher-audio-plugins ubuntu-desktop ubuntu-session unity-control-center unity-control-center-signon unity-settings-daemon unity-webapps-common unity-webapps-qml unity-webapps-service vlc webapp-container webbrowser-app
```

## 3 reinstall the packages, with the pulseaudio one to the previous version

```
sudo apt install libpulsedsp=1:8.0-0ubuntu3 pulseaudio=1:8.0-0ubuntu3 libpulse0=1:8.0-0ubuntu3 libpulse-mainloop-glib0=1:8.0-0ubuntu3 pulseaudio-module-x11=1:8.0-0ubuntu3 pulseaudio-module-bluetooth=1:8.0-0ubuntu3 pulseaudio-utils=1:8.0-0ubuntu3 checkbox-converged checkbox-gui gdm3 gnome-control-center gnome-orca gnome-session gnome-settings-daemon gnome-shell gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio indicator-bluetooth indicator-sound libasound2-plugins libcanberra-pulse libespeak1 libfluidsynth1 libfreerdp-plugins-standard liboxideqt-qmlplugin liboxideqtcore0 liboxideqtquick0 libqt5feedback5 libqt5multimedia5 libsdl-image1.2 libsdl1.2debian libunity-webapps0 qml-module-qtfeedback qml-module-ubuntu-components qml-module-ubuntu-test qml-module-ubuntu-web qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-toolkit-plugin speech-dispatcher speech-dispatcher-audio-plugins ubuntu-desktop ubuntu-session unity-control-center unity-control-center-signon unity-settings-daemon unity-webapps-common unity-webapps-qml unity-webapps-service vlc webapp-container webbrowser-app
```

## 4 Remove the user config file

```
rm -r ~/.config/pulse/*
```

## 5 Shutdown the computer then turn it on again (don't reboot).

## 6 Enjoy sound again :)

Comment: what do you mean by keep track?

Comment: I meant copy the list of packages that will be removed. You will find the list below `The following packages will be REMOVED:` when you purge the package with the first command. Don't forget to exclude the seven packages of item #1 from this list. On item #3 copy/paste this list after `sudo apt install libpulsedsp=1:8.0-0ubuntu3 pulseaudio=1:8.0-0ubuntu3 libpulse0=1:8.0-0ubuntu3 libpulse-mainloop-glib0=1:8.0-0ubuntu3 pulseaudio-module-x11=1:8.0-0ubuntu3 pulseaudio-module-bluetooth=1:8.0-0ubuntu3 pulseaudio-utils=1:8.0-0ubuntu3`.